# Airflow copy bigquery table to GCS without column names

Tags: airflow

I know we can use airflow bigquery_to_gcs operator to copy a bigquery table to GCS but that will copy the column names as well. I have a use case that should have only the column values but not the names. Is it possible?

fruit  | any_value |

pear   | pear      |

apple  | pear      |

banana | apple     |

I want my csv file to be something like this

pear,pear
apple,pear
apple,pear

Whereas the output if I use bigquery_to_gcs is

fruit,any_value
pear,pear
apple,pear
apple,pear

Comment: do you know how you would do this in bigquery, but you don't know how to make it in airflow? is this a case?

Comment: I know how to copy a table to gcs with column names using airflow. I want to know if there is a way to copy the table to GCS using airflow without column names.

Comment: ok. so it is purely airflow question - got it

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set `print_header=False` on the task instance.

See details here http://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_to_gcs.html